# Azure Functions with runtime 2; binding extensions not automatically created

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

When I deploy my Azure Function project to my Function App based on the v2 runtime, the binding extensions my project depend on (Azure Storage in my case), are not automatically created.

I deploy my project with an extensions.csproj file on the root, but after deploying I have to manually run the following command to create a bin and obj folder at wwwroot.

`dotnet build extensions.csproj -o bin --no-incremental --packages D:\home\.nuget`

If I understand correctly, this should happen automatically.

Comment: Are you using the correct version of the packages/extensions? Version should be >=3.0.0.

Comment: I'm using version 3.0 of the Nuget packages: 
```<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.0.0" />```

Comment: @Ramon How do you generate function code and deploy it, using function core tools?

Comment: @JerryLiu, yes I use function core tools version 2. Runtime is nodejs btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For deployment by CLI `func azure functionapp publish`**

Function core tools use zip deployment to deploy functions, in this way, kudu doesn't build project [by default](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#enabledisable-build-actions). To enable the feature, set `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` to `true` in Application settings on portal.

As for why the default setting is false, zip deployment usually requires the content to be deployed including all related files hence there's no need to build again.

For Azure function core tools, we usually use command `func extensions install` to [register extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#register-extensions) for input/output binding when extensions are not installed automatically like we create trigger from template. This is why command `func start` and `func azure functionapp publish` doesn't build `extensions.csproj`, extensions are supposed to be installed before we run or publish functions.

**Update for DevOps deployment**

With Azure pipeline, we need to build `extensions.csporj` before archive files. Add a .NET Core build task, arguments are `-o bin`.

If you want kudu to build project, go to Deployment Center under Platform features. Choose VSTS as a CI repository and kudu will build and deploy project for you.

Comment: I don't see the relationship between Function Core Tools and deployments in this case. I'm using Azure DevOps (VSTS) to build my project (TypeScript transpiling) after which the zip is released to the Function App. 

To make it work, I've added a `dotnet build extensions.csproj -o bin --no-incremental --packages D:\home\.nuget` to my build definition after the bin/obj folders are added to the zip. That makes it work now.

It's pretty confusing how this all has to come together with all the scenario's that exist.

Comment: @Ramon Got it, you say using function core tools so I assume you use it to deploy your code directly to Azure(code is built by kudu), and that's the case I describe above. Will do some investigation and reply to you later.

Comment: I understand the confusion. With using function core tools I only meant during development we develop locally with function core tools (instead of manually creating functions on the Function App in Azure). The rest is handled by our CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps. Happy to hear from you about your findings!

Comment: @Ramon Sorry for the delay. The extensions need to be installed exactly under `functionappfolder/bin`, build command needs `-o bin` arguments. This process works for me, did you miss this argument so that the `bin` included before doesn't work?

Comment: I did provide this command: `dotnet build extensions.csproj -o bin --no-incremental --packages D:\home\.nuget`. So I included the bin argument. The build in VSTS works fine (if VSTS is actually working, that is more of a problem these days..). My question was more; do I have to include the bin/obj folder in my build at all or does Azure handle this based on the extensions.csproj.

Comment: @Ramon If you define your own build definition in vsts, which means you want everything under control, so Azure doesn't handle the extensions(i.e. build again) for you. The content to be published should include `bin` folder generated by the build command. If you hand over the build process to Azure server(kudu), `bin` is unnecessary, in this way, vsts is only used as a repository.

Answer (score 0):

When using Visual Studio, you'll be referencing the extension packages directly from your project in order to use their attributes and other types, so Visual Studio handles the installation process, but registration still needs to be performed.

This is handled by a custom build task, added by the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator` NuGet package, which **must be explicitly referenced** (this will be automatically brought in by the SDK/Visual Studio tools in a future update).

These are the steps you must follow to use the CosmosDB extension mentioned in our previous example:

1.Add a reference to the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage` NuGet package

2.Add a reference to the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator`

3.Build the project

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Binding-Extensions-Management).

Comment: Thanks. I'm referencing the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator` package correctly I guess. I'm not using Visual Studio btw. Is my assumption correct that you don't have to deploy the project with the bin/obj folder included and that de Azure Functions runtime (v2) will do the installation of the extensions? Or should I build my project myself and include the obj/bin folders before deploying into Azure?