# Install Azure Functions extension via pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've got an Azure Function v2 written in nodejs, however, I'm struggling to get it running on Azure.
It works locally just fine, also when deployed from VS Code it works just fine. The issue starts when I do a zip deployment from a pipeline.
To be precise: The Sendgrid binding extension doesn't register.

[image: kudu wwwroot]

When browsing to KUDU and looking at my function app in `wwwroot` I have my `extensions.csproj` with the following content:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <WarningsAsErrors></WarningsAsErrors>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>**</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Shouldn't this automatically take care of installing the extension?

Comment: Can you please check the Azure Function app version on Azure. Hope both are matching well

Comment: `from a pipeline` Do you mean Azure pipeline?

Comment: version is `~2`.
@JerryLiu it's really just a zip deploy. That it's an Azure pipeline is probably not too important. Unless there's something in there that can install the extension for me.

Comment: @DavidO'Brien If it's about Azure pipeline, we can install extensions there(in build pipeline). Or if it's a simple zip deploy, we need to install extensions locally as Azure won't do it for us. Zip deploy requires everything is included.

Comment: @JerryLiu do you mean I need to include the `bin` folder in my zip file for the Azure Function?
How would I do it in my build pipeline? Do I just run `dotnet build extensions.csproj` before zipping it up?

Comment: @JerryLiu found your comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703296/azure-functions-with-runtime-2-binding-extensions-not-automatically-created running `dotnet build` to create the `bin` and include it in the zip file works.

Comment: Through @JerryLiu's comment I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703296/azure-functions-with-runtime-2-binding-extensions-not-automatically-created which answers this question.

Comment: @DavidO'Brien Do you mind I post an answer here for others to refer? Of course you could do it yourself if not bother.

Comment: @JerryLiu sure, go ahead. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidO'Brien  You're welcome. Job is done. Do you mind accepting it to close the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zip deploy requires everything being archived hence we need to install extensions in build pipeline. Add a .NET Core build task, arguments are `-o bin` which outputs dlls in `bin` folder.