# Function App with Event Grid Trigger Binding - Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-eventgrid, azure-function-app

I hope someone is able to guide me in the right direction.

I am trying to implement the following:

***Event Grid -> Function App -> Storage Account***

I am also trying to implement the above through ARM templates and Azure DevOps deployment, but I am a bit confused on how to add the Event Grid Bindings to my Function App (.Net) code Files in Azure Repos.

I know in the documentation it says that i need to install the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid" NuGet package, but how is this done through Azure DevOps?

Currently my Release Pipelines are set up as follows:

1) Deploy Function App, Storage Account, Event Grid
2) Deploy Function App Code
3) Get Master Key of function app
4) Create Event Grid Subscription.

Tasks 1-3 execute correctly, but (4) fails with "URL endpoint validation failed" - which im guessing is because I havent installed Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid packages correctly in my functions files in Azure repos.
When i set everything up manually and install the Event Grid trigger in the portal, I can easily create the Event Grid Subscription without issues.

How do I 'install' Event Grid Trigger NuGet Packages in Azure DevOps if my Function App code is in Azure Repos?

Much Appreciated.

Comment: looks like it was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703296/azure-functions-with-runtime-2-binding-extensions-not-automatically-created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know in the documentation it says that i need to install the
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid" NuGet package, but how
>   is this done through Azure DevOps?

Just as answered in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703296/azure-functions-with-runtime-2-binding-extensions-not-automatically-created), you need to add a `dotnet restore` task to restore the package and  a `.NET Core build` task to build the extensions project before archive files.

Besides, we can install and use [Event Grid Subscription Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RasmusWatjen.EventGridSubscriptionExtension) to create and modify event grid subscriptions in Azure DevOps pipeline.

Below blogs for your reference, hope that helps :

- [Automatic Subscription of Azure Functions to Event Grid](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1267073/Automatic-Subscription-of-Azure-Functions-to-Event)
- [ARM Template for Event Grid integration with a new Azure
  Function](https://blog.brooksjc.com/2019/07/19/arm-template-for-event-grid-integration-with-a-new-azure-function/)